# How to set different permissions for different methods such as POST and List when use Django REST Framework's ListCreateAPIView

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I built a `Follow` model to record the social networking behaviour and would like to simulate the following action. Every authenticated user can follow the others.

```
class Follow(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    follower = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="followers")
    follow_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('user', 'follower')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s, %s' % (self.user.username, self.follower)
```

And the `FollowSerializer` is:

```
class FollowSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Follow
        field = ('user', 'follower', 'follow_time')
```

The view that I am using is:

```
class FollowingEnumByUserID(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = FollowSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        follower_id = self.kwargs['pk']
        return Follow.objects.filter(follower=follower_id)
```

I am registering it in the urls as:

```
url(r'^api/users/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/following/$', views.FollowingEnumByUserID.as_view()),
```

Every authenticated user can view the following relation, no restricts. But I would like to just allow the authenticated user to add the following relation by himself/herself, which means there should be `request.user == follower`. How can I do this?

---

I would like to add the `FollowingDelete` view to just allow the user to add a following relation by himself/herself.

So I updated the url.py as:

```
url(r'^api/users/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/following/$', views.FollowingEnumByUserID.as_view()),
url(r'^api/users/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/following/(?P<following_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.FollowingDelete.as_view()),
```

The permission that I am using is:

```
class IsFollowerOrReadOnly(permissions.BasePermission):
    """
    View-level permission to allow the follower to edit the following relation
    """

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            return True

        try:
            follower = User.objects.get(id=view.kwargs["pk"])
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            #Reject any request for an invalid user
            return False

        return follower == request.user
```

And the views are:

```
class FollowingEnumByUserID(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = FollowSerializer
    permission_class = (IsFollowerOrReadOnly)

    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        List all the people the input user is following
        """
        follower_id = self.kwargs['pk']
        return Follow.objects.filter(follower=follower_id)

class FollowingDelete(generics.DestroyAPIView):
    serializer_class = FollowSerializer
    permission_class = (IsAuthenticated, IsFollowerOrReadOnly)

    def get_queryset(self):
        user_id = self.kwargs['following_id']
        follower_id = self.kwargs['pk']
        return Follow.objects.filter(user=user_id, follower=follower_id)
```

Now the questions are:

1. The permission class doesn't work totally.
2. How to rewrite the `DestroyAPIView`, should I override the `get_queryset` function?

Answer (score 1):

Django REST framework [provides custom permission handling](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/) that allows you to handle complex permissions on the view and object level. In order to do what you are looking for, you are going to have to [create a custom permission](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#custom-permissions), but it's surprisingly easy.

> Every authenticated user can follow the others.

DRF provides an `IsAuthenticated` permission that allows you to do this very easily. All you have to do is [add it to the `permission_classes` on the view, or globally through the settings](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#setting-the-permission-policy).

```
from rest_framework import permissions

class FollowingEnumByUserID(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = FollowSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated, )

    def get_queryset(self):
        follower_id = self.kwargs['pk']
        return Follow.objects.filter(follower=follower_id)
```

There is another restriction, which is the one that requires the custom permission class.

> But I would like to just allow the authenticated user to add the following relation by himself/herself

This requires checking the request method (which I'm assuming is `POST`) and also the user who is being followed.

Lets start off with the easy check, the request method. Django REST framework provides permission classes that check the request method, [such as `IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#isauthenticatedorreadonly), so [we can look at the code](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/4ce4132e08ba7764f120c71eeebdbaefee281689/rest_framework/permissions.py#L59-L69) to see how it is being done. From there it's just a matter of having a check against the request type.

```
class PostIfFollower(BasePermission):
    """
    The request is not POST or the request user is the follower.
    """

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if request.method != "POST":
            return True

        return False
```

This code will reject all requests that come in using the `POST` method, while allowing all others. The second step in creating this permission is doing the user check, so only the follower can add new people that they are following. This requires getting the follower and checking that against `request.user`.

```
    class PostIfFollower(BasePermission):
        """
        The request is not POST or the request user is the follower.
        """

        def has_permission(self, request, view):
            if request.method != "POST":
                return True

            try:
                follower = User.objects.get(id=view.kwargs["pk"])
            except User.DoesNotExist:
                # Reject any requests for an invalid user
                return False

            return follower == request.user
```

This builds upon the last permission class by getting the user from the url (not allowing it if the user doesn't exist) and checking if they are the current user.

Comment: Hi, @Kevin, could you please answer the updated question as above?

Comment: @Scofield77 At a first glance, your modified code _looks like it should work_ for what you are trying to do. I would recommend [creating a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) instead of modifying this one, as it appears to be a different problem. Also, welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 1):

After I modified the typos, the permission class works now:

```
class FollowingEnumByUserID(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = FollowSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsFollowerOrReadOnly,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        List all the people the input user is following
        """
        follower_id = self.kwargs['pk']
        return Follow.objects.filter(follower=follower_id)

class FollowingDelete(generics.DestroyAPIView):
    serializer_class = FollowSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, IsFollowerOrReadOnly,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        user_id = self.kwargs['following_id']
        follower_id = self.kwargs['pk']
        return Follow.objects.filter(user=user_id, follower=follower_id)
```

And I make the `FollowingDelete` view work successfully by overriding the `get_object()` function.

```
def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
    user_id = self.kwargs['following_id']
    follower_id = self.kwargs['pk']

    try:
        return Follow.objects.get(user=user_id, follower=follower_id)
    except Follow.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("No such following relation")
```